# Ergodicity of this Markov Chain

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, markov-chains

I was recently involved in a debate with a friend over the following graph, and whether it is ergodic or not. In the following diagram, each edge has a strictly positive probability of being travelled on:

[image]

I thought it was ergodic because of the definition from [this source](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~valko/courses/331/MC2.pdf), which said that a Markov Chain is ergodic if "if it is possible to eventually get from every state to every other state with positive probability", which is clearly the case here.

However, my friend quoted [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Ergodicity), alleging that the Markov Chain in question is not ergodic, because it is periodic: he said that all cycles have lengths that are multiples of three.

Who is right, and who is wrong, and why?

Comment: See here as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152491/is-ergodic-markov-chain-both-irreducible-and-aperiodic-or-just-irreducible

Answer (score 1):

If you have drawn the only non-zero transitions then the Markov chain has transition matrix (listing the states in the order north, west, east, south)
$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
This matrix has the following powers
$$P^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
$$P^3 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$P^4 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
so note that $P^4=P$. Recall that elements of $P^n$ indexed $(i,j)$ represent the probability of being in state $j$ at time $n$ given that at time $0$ the process was in state $i$. You can see that any time to return to a given state must be a multiple of 3, so the chain is periodic with period 3. (Your friend is right, note that the definition of ergodicity requires the chain to be aperiodic.)

Comment: So the 'definition' I got from that .pdf was erroneous?

Comment: Yes, the definition was missing a detail. Ergodicity is about time averages being the save as space averages. If we ran a single simulation for a long time and took averages (time average) or we ran a large number of short simulations (space average) we should get the same answers. Introducing the aperiodicity requirement is important to make sure the space average isn't unduly influenced by the time you run those shorter simulations for. (A good reference for his in Harchol-Balter's 'Performance Modeling and Design of Computer Systems' http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139226424.008)