# Ergodic markov chain and irreducible

Tags: markov-chains

I have been reading about ergodic markov chain. Does ergodic markov chain has to be irreducible and aperiodic? Is it sufficient to satisfy irreducibility?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152491/is-ergodic-markov-chain-both-irreducible-and-aperiodic-or-just-irreducible